# I have downloaded syncfusion, I don't know how to run syncfusion demo code . Please, anyone, know about it. this error occur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, syncfusion

I have downloaded `syncfusion`, I don't know how to run `syncfusion` demo code . Please, anyone, know about it.

**this error occur:**

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR!
> diagrambuilder@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts-ts start` npm ERR! Exit
> status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the diagrambuilder@0.1.0 start
> script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\Ayushi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-01-29T10_14_59_748Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

In package.json, you need to specify a start script like so:

```
  "scripts": {
  "start": "<START CODE GOES HERE>"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the customer requirements and he need to add the script in package.json file. Please find the below code snippet.

```
"scripts": { 
    "start": "react-scripts start" 
  },
```

We have created the react sample for your reference. Please find the below link.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/313051/7z/react115349736